# TabHost's getTabWidget() returns null although the object contains mTabWidget

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost, robolectric, fragment-tab-host

In my Robolectric test I run my fragment by:

```
sut = new TestedFragment();
SupportFragmentTestUtil.startFragment(sut);
```

In fragment's `onCreateView` I have `android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost` on which I try to get its `tabWidget` using:

```
inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);
tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) inflatedView.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();
tabHost.setup(getActivity(), fragmentManager, android.R.id.tabcontent);
tabHost.getTabWidget(); //returns null
```

This line returns null although set up breakpoint on this line shows me that `tabHost`'s `mTabWidget` has value of 
`android.widget.TabWidget{7a4d42e6 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0 #1020013 android:id/tabs}` so why do I get `null`?

The code works on android, i doesn't work in roboelectric unit test

Comment: Could you please add the full robolectric test code?

Comment: Other lines of my code are not invoked. Earlier I just `@RunWith`testRunner and I target sdk, and manifest

Answer (score 0):

Robolectric use shadow classes to hide some real code. Because not all can be done at JVM or must be adjusted.

Open the class ShadowTabHost and set a breakpoint in the getTabWidget method. Then you can see why you get null.

Answer (score -1):

```
Try this

 public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("first").setIndicator("First").setContent(new Intent(this  ,FirstActivity.class )));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("second").setIndicator("Second").setContent(new Intent(this , SecondActivity.class )));
        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


    }
    }
```

Comment: first: he is using `FragmentTabHost` this answer do not apply ... second: `TabActivity` is deprecated

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I don't want to change source code which normally works - I'd like to have a working test

Comment: Can you post some code so as to understand where you are stuck